# reduce convert array to unique array property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I use reduce to convert

```
[ { type: [ 'apple', 'google' ], currency: 'usd' }, 
  { type: [ 'apple', 'huawei' ], currency: 'eur' }, 
   ]
```

to

```
[{
  type: 'apple',
  currency: ['usd','eur']
}, {
  type: 'google',
  currency: ['usd']
}, {
  type: 'huawei',
  currency: ['eur']
}]
```

Do I have to use anything else other than one reduce function? I struggle at making array type into type in property.

Comment: There seems to be an error in your output - shouldn't the "google" type only have "usd" as a currency?

Answer (score 2):

One approach combined `Object.values()` with `Array#reduce()` to transform the data as required.

Here, `.reduce()` is used to build a mapping that relates your company "types" to arrays storing "currency" strings. Once that mapping has been obtained it's passed to `Object.values()` which extracts the mapped values to an array:

```js
const input = [{
    type: ['apple', 'google'],
    currency: 'usd'
  },  
  {
    type: ['apple', 'huawei'],
    currency: 'eur'
  },  
];

/* Transform the mapping that is build to an array of values for
that mapping */
const output = Object.values(input.reduce((map, item) => {

  item.type.forEach(type => {

    /* Fetch or create a new "value" that contains the type and
       currency array for the current company type being iterated */
    const value = map[type] || {
      type: type,
      currency: []
    };
    
    /* Add the currency of the current item to the currency array
    of the mapped value being updated */
    value.currency.push(item.currency);

    map[type] = value;
  });

  return map;
}, {}))

console.log(output)
```